# CentOs Mail Server Limit per 30 Minutes

Tags: email, centos, limit, plesk

I am getting the Error "Recipient address rejected: sorry, max 50 requests per 30 minutes (in reply to RCPT TO command))" in my "/var/log/maillog" log File. I know this is because I've sent to many Emails, but I would like to raise it to about 200. 
But i cant find the configuration file for my Mailserver. I use Plesk and actually dont know what Mail-Server is installed. 
Does anybody know if there is some standard config file?

Answer (score 0):

This message comes from [postfwd](https://postfwd.org/) (postfix firewall daemon), which is not shipped or managed by Plesk.

To change limit, modify the corresponding rule in `/etc/postfix/postfwd.cf` file:

```
       action=rate(client_address/200/1800/450 4.7.1 sorry, max 200 requests per 30 minutes)
```

Refer to [postfwd documentation](http://postfwd.org/doc.html#actions) for more detailed info.

Alternatively, you can disable this service completely and use native [Plesk outgoing mail limits](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/mail-settings/limiting-outgoing-mail.73362/) handler.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer! Is this service automatically disabled if I enable Plesks "Limit on outgoing messages" or do I have to disable it first.

Comment: I don't think that Plesk is aware of this service, so it is required to disable it manually. `systemctl stop postfwd && systemctl disable postfwd` for CentOS 7 or `service postfwd stop && chkconfig postfwd off` for older ones.